# Replicate a column VectorXd in order to construct a MatrixXd in Eigen, C++

Tags: c++, eigen, replicate

Let's assume that we have a 10x20 real matrix:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd A(10,20);
A.setRandom();
```

We would like to construct a 10x10 matrix of the form

`B = [v v ... v v]`

where `v` is a column vector of length `10`. For this vector, `v`, each element is the squared norm of each row of A, that is:

`v = ( ||x_1||^2, ||x_2||^2, ..., ||x_10||^2,)^T`,

where `x_j` denotes the j-th row of A.

What is the most efficient way to construct matrix `B`?

I could construct `v` as follows:

```
Eigen::VectorXd v(10);
for (int i=1; i<10; i++)
{
    v(i) = A.row(i).squaredNorm();
}
```

I think that this step cannot be solved without a `for` loop. How could I replicate this column 10 times such that `B` is filled as discussed above?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong. The loop can be avoided by doing a [`rowwise`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReductionsVisitorsBroadcasting.html#title5) operation. Then, the [replication](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__QuickRefPage.html#title11) can be done as follows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>

int main ()
{
    Eigen::MatrixXd A(10,20), B, C;
    A.setRandom();

    Eigen::VectorXd v(10);
    v = A.rowwise().squaredNorm();

    B = v.replicate(1,10);

    std::cout << B << "\n\n";

    return 0;
}
```

It can also be written in a single line as

```
    B =  A.rowwise().squaredNorm().replicate(1,10);
```

I highly recommend reading the [documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/). It's pretty well written.